# How to serialize multiple models data in django-rest when models classes are generated from legacy database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

1. Model classes are generated from existing database, do not show foreign keys relation in generated model classes.

   ```
   $ python manage.py inspectdb

   $ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
   ```
2. Goal is to get related data from multiple tables.
3. Following is my serializer snippet:

   ```
   from .models import JobsList, JobsCategories
   class JobsCategoriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = JobsCategories
       fields = ('name', 'id',)

   class JobsListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       category = JobsCategoriesSerializer(source='job_category', many=True)
       class Meta:
           model  = JobsList
           fields = ('job_title', 'category')
   ```
4. Error:
   Request Method:  GET
   Request URL:     http://localhost:8000/jobs/6  /?access_token=bBN6BSLlYi8TXF3SkLEOMbtsKfD3xX&format=json
   Django Version:  1.8.3
   Exception Type:  TypeError
   Exception Value:

   'long' object is not iterable

5.1 The response is:

```
{"id":6,"userid":491,"company_id":4,"job_title":"Web Designer","job_info":"We require a web designer.","min_exp":0,"max_exp":1,"min_ctc":null,"max_ctc":null,"open_positions":0,"location":"18","hr_email":"","contact_number":"","job_category":3,"job_referred":"0","added_by":"0","status":"1","date_time":null,"expiry_date":null,"job_meta":"web graphics bodhan designer funvestfinancials","job_type":"0"}
```

** I want job_category which is an id replaced with category name**

6. I need help to get category name with job data jobs_category and jobs_list are two separate model classes generated by reverse engineering from existing database. Kindly help me if this is possible in this way I am doing or if it is doable in another.
7. Job list model:

   ```
   class JobsList(models.Model):
       .....
       job_category    = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
       .....
   ```
8. Category model:

   ```
   class JobsCategories(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      status = models.CharField(max_length=1)

      class Meta:
           managed = False
           db_table = 'jobs_categories'

       def __unicode__(self):
            return '%s' % (self.name)
   ```

   ** I need categories name whose id is in job_category column jobs_list table. Issue is the model classes generated from legacy database do not have relations **

Comment: Please post the related code for views and models.

Comment: Updated my question with job_list and category models. Can we get data from these two tables by using above sterilizers classes

Comment: let me try your solution !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [`to_representation()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior) method of the `JobsListSerializer` to get your desired response.

You need to do something like:

```
class JobsListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model  = JobsList
        ...

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        serialized_data = super(JobsListSerializer, self).to_representation(obj) # original serialized data
        job_category_id = serialized_data.get('job_category') # get job category id from original serialized data
        job_category = JobsCategories.objects.get(id=job_category_id) # get the object from db
        serialized_data['job_category'] = job_category.name # replace id with category name
        return serialized_data # return modified serialized data
```

Comment: Awesome !! now category name coming in response thanks